# Uncaught error in markup://ui:click Error in Salesforce1

Tags: error-messages

We are getting the following error when we try to click the "my tasks" list views from Salesforce1.  Not sure what it means or even where to start.  Any suggestions?  We have quite a bit of custom Visualforce and code in standard Salesforce, but didn't expect it to impact SF1.

```
Uncaught error in markup://ui:click : undefined is not an object (evaluating 'c.get')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Salesforce support has confirmed that the above error is due to a Visualforce page that has been assigned to override the standard page.  The page is not 'mobile friendly' and so SF1 throws the error.  Below is the actual response.

> The error is caused by the "New Task" button being overridden by a VF
>   page that is not available for mobile.
>
> 2 possible workarounds as of now:
>
> First option is to not override the "New Task" button  Second option
>   is to make the VF page "populateTaskPage" available on mobile